# Classification of square roots of line bundles and metalinear/metaplectic structures

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, line-bundles, chern-classes, geometric-quantization

Reading some books and articles about geometric quantization I got confused about the classification of square roots of complex line bundles over a manifold. Consider the group of isomorphism classes of complex line bundles $L$ over a closed manifold $M$. This group is isomorphic to $H^2(M;\mathbb Z)$ via the Chern class $L\mapsto c_1(L)$. Consider further the exact sequence $$0\to\mathbb Z\stackrel{\beta}{\to}\mathbb Z\stackrel{\gamma}{\to} \mathbb Z_2\to 0,$$ where $\beta$ is multiplication by $2$ and the bit of the corresponding long exact sequence in Cech-cohomology $$H^1(M;\mathbb Z)\stackrel{\gamma_1}{\to}H^1(M;\mathbb Z_2)\stackrel{\delta_1}{\to}H^2(M;\mathbb Z)\stackrel{\beta_2}{\to}H^2(M;\mathbb Z).$$ Then under the isomorphism $L\mapsto c_1(L)$, the set of square roots of the trivial line bundle is in bijection with $$\ker\beta_2=\mathrm{Im}\,\delta_1\cong H^1(M;\mathbb Z_2)/\mathrm{Im}\,\gamma_1.$$ Now Appendix A.3 in [1](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/geometric-quantization-9780198502708?cc=de&lang=en&) or page 4 in [2](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-58/issue-1/On-the-pairing-of-polarizations/cmp/1103901363.full) say on the other hand that the choice of the square root is labelled/parametrized by $H^1(M;\mathbb Z_2)$. An analogous statement is made on page 56 (bullet point 4.) in [3](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/9904008) and on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaplectic_structure#cite_note-2) for metalinear/metaplectic structures on $M$ when $M$ is symplectic and [2](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-58/issue-1/On-the-pairing-of-polarizations/cmp/1103901363.full) observes that metalinear structures are in bijection with square roots of the canonical bundle.

So: is it true that $\mathrm{Im}\,\gamma_1=0$ or am I overlooking something else (for instance about the equivalence of the set of square roots and of metalinear structures)?

[1](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/geometric-quantization-9780198502708?cc=de&lang=en&) [Woodhouse, Geometric Quantization, Second Edition](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/geometric-quantization-9780198502708?cc=de&lang=en&)

[2](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-58/issue-1/On-the-pairing-of-polarizations/cmp/1103901363.full) [Rawnsley, On the pairing of polarizations](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-58/issue-1/On-the-pairing-of-polarizations/cmp/1103901363.full)

[3](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/9904008) [Echeverria-Enriquez, Muñoz-Lecanda, Roman-Roy, Victoria-Monge, Mathematical Foundations of Geometric Quantization](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/9904008)

Comment: The kernel of $\beta_2$ is isomorphism classes of complex line bundles which have the property that their tensor square can be trivialized, but without the choice of this trivialization. Usually a "square root" means that you include the choice of trivialization as well. The difference is exactly the image of $\gamma_1$.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries Thank you! It makes perfect sense and indeed this is the definition of square root is given in Rawnsley (which I overlooked)